# Sharing data between User Controls without access to the Page class

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have two user controls and each one of them needs to call the same service to get some data. Since these two user controls are on the same page - this would result in calling the service twice, which is not ideal from performance perspective.

These controls are part of a CMS, so I don't have access to the aspx page - I mean, I cannot add a property to the Page class and use that.

One way I am thinking this can be done is storing the data in the user Session.

So, each of the user controls will check the Session and if it is null - it will call the service and populate the Session.

What are my options apart from using the Session?

EDIT: Each of the user controls needs to call the following service, which is part of the CMS:

```
 var personalizationService = new PersonalizationService();
 var userSegments = personalizationService.GetUserSegments();
 //get data based on userSegments
```

The thing is - these two user controls can be on the same page, but at some point the user may decide to remove one of the user controls, or add a third one to the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a bad idea. User controls should be self contained and not know about their environment. Think of a grid view.

Aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" />
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView2" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = Database.GetDataTable();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataSoure = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

`GridView` doesn't pull data from Session, and neither should you! Instead, set a property in your user control to pass the data in.

If the data has relevance outside of just the current page then you *might* store it in session, but the user control shouldn't pull the data from Session, your page should pull the data from Session and pass it into the user control

```
if(Session["ImportantData"] == null)
    {
    Session[ImportantData] = Database.GetImportantData();
    }
MyUserControl1.Data = Session["ImportantData"] as ImportantDataClass;
MyUserControl2.Data = Session["ImportantData"] as ImportantDataClass;
```

---

In response to your edit...

```
var personalizationService = new PersonalizationService();
MyUserControl1.PersonalizationService = personalizationService;
MyUserControl2.PersonalizationService = personalizationService;
```

By the way, you shouldn't do `new PersonalizationService();` Ideally, you should be getting that from dependency injection, so you can swap out the implementation from a centralized location. I tend to use Ninject, which can do attribute injection.

```
[Ninject]
public IPersonalizationService personalizationService {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl1.PersonalizationService = personalizationService;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I was thinking of doing with the Session, but was wondering if there was a better way. See my Edit above

Comment: your code of setting the PersonalizationService property of the user controls is happenning in the Page's Load event, correct? And also the page assumes that these two user controls are on that page, which may not be the case should the user decides the remove one of them. 
The more I think, the more I believe the Session is the only option

Comment: @VeselinVasilev Yes, my assumption is that it's happening in the page's load event. But that doesn't mean that Session is the only option or even a good option. If you're adding the user controls dynamically, then pass the service to the controls when you add them. It's that simple. for example `public void AddControl1(){ /* add control to page */ control.PersonalizationService = personalizationService; }` Don't use Session, the *user controls should be self contained* and not depend on their environment.

Comment: Agree with you, but those user controls are widgets in the CMS and they are dragged and dropped by content editors at any time on any page. So, that makes the things a bit more complex.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev No, it doesn't. Run some code when a widget is added, and pass the service to it.